# Improving data validation efficiency in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I load data from a CSV into Pandas and do validation on some of the fields like this:

```
(1.5s) loans['net_mortgage_margin'] = loans['net_mortgage_margin'].map(lambda x: convert_to_decimal(x))
(1.5s) loans['current_interest_rate'] = loans['current_interest_rate'].map(lambda x: convert_to_decimal(x))
(1.5s) loans['net_maximum_interest_rate'] = loans['net_maximum_interest_rate'].map(lambda x: convert_to_decimal(x))

(48s)  loans['credit_score'] = loans.apply(lambda row: get_minimum_score(row), axis=1)
(< 1s) loans['loan_age'] = ((loans['factor_date'] - loans['first_payment_date']) / np.timedelta64(+1, 'M')).round() + 1
(< 1s) loans['months_to_roll'] = ((loans['next_rate_change_date'] - loans['factor_date']) / np.timedelta64(+1, 'M')).round() + 1
(34s)  loans['first_payment_change_date'] = loans.apply(lambda x: validate_date(x, 'first_payment_change_date', loans.columns), axis=1)
(37s)  loans['first_rate_change_date'] = loans.apply(lambda x: validate_date(x, 'first_rate_change_date', loans.columns), axis=1)

(39s)  loans['first_payment_date'] = loans.apply(lambda x: validate_date(x, 'first_payment_date', loans.columns), axis=1)
(39s)  loans['maturity_date'] = loans.apply(lambda x: validate_date(x, 'maturity_date', loans.columns), axis=1)
(37s)  loans['next_rate_change_date'] = loans.apply(lambda x: validate_date(x, 'next_rate_change_date', loans.columns), axis=1)
(36s)  loans['first_PI_date'] = loans.apply(lambda x: validate_date(x, 'first_PI_date', loans.columns), axis=1)

(36s)  loans['servicer_name'] = loans.apply(lambda row: row['servicer_name'][:40].upper().strip(), axis=1)
(38s)  loans['state_name'] = loans.apply(lambda row: str(us.states.lookup(row['state_code'])), axis=1)
(33s) loans['occupancy_status'] = loans.apply(lambda row: get_occupancy_type(row), axis=1)
(37s)  loans['original_interest_rate_range'] = loans.apply(lambda row: get_interest_rate_range(row, 'original'), axis=1)
(36s)  loans['current_interest_rate_range'] = loans.apply(lambda row: get_interest_rate_range(row, 'current'), axis=1)
(33s)  loans['valid_credit_score'] = loans.apply(lambda row: validate_credit_score(row), axis=1)
(60s)  loans['origination_year'] = loans['first_payment_date'].map(lambda x: x.year if x.month > 2 else x.year - 1)
(< 1s) loans['number_of_units'] = loans['unit_count'].map(lambda x: '1' if x == 1 else '2-4')
(32s)  loans['property_type'] = loans.apply(lambda row: validate_property_type(row), axis=1)
```

Most of these are functions that find the `row` value, a few directly convert an element to something else, but all in all, these are ran for the entire dataframe line by line.  When this code was written, the data frames were small enough that this was not an issue.  The code is now, however, being adapted to take in significantly larger tables, such that this part of the code takes far too long.

What is the best way to optimize this?  My first thought was to go row by row, but apply all of these functions/transformations on the row once (i.e. for row in df, do func1, func2, ..., func21), but I'm not sure if that is the best way to deal with that.  Is there a way to avoid lambda to get the same result, for example, since I assume it's lambda that takes a long time?  Running Python 2.7 in case that matters.

Edit: most of these calls run at about the same rate per row (a few are pretty fast).  This is a dataframe with 277,659 rows, which is in the 80th percentile in terms of size.

Edit2: example of a function:

```
def validate_date(row, date_type, cols):
    date_element = row[date_type]
    if date_type not in cols:
        return np.nan
    if pd.isnull(date_element) or len(str(date_element).strip()) < 2:  # can be blank, NaN, or "0"
        return np.nan
    if date_element.day == 1:
        return date_element
    else:
        next_month = date_element + relativedelta(months=1)
        return pd.to_datetime(dt.date(next_month.year, next_month.month, 1))
```

This is similar to the longest call (origination_year) which extracts values from a date object (year, month, etc.).  Others, like property_type for example, are just checking for irregular values (e.g. "N/A", "NULL", etc.) but still take a little while just to go through each one.

Comment: If you already have a function `convert_to_decimal`, it's just clutter to write `lambda x: convert_to_decimal(x)`. It's the same as writing `lambda y: (lambda x: convert_to_decimal(x))(y)`

Comment: Question 1: **what** is slow? You have 4-5 functions that we can't see the code of, some, like `convert_to_decimal` I hope are fast, others, like `validate_date` where you're passing it a column *might* be the problems, but we can only speculate. At the very least, sprinkling in some `print(time.time())` calls would be helpful.

Comment: Edited with time per call.  It's not that any one specific call is slow; it's that in total they're adding to more time than ideal, and at the very least it seems like not calling every row over and over should help, but I don't know if that's just replacing 8.5 minutes with 7.6 minutes.

Comment: Post an example of your functions that take a while (how about `validate_date`).

Comment: Done.  Validate_date doesn't take in columns, just column names per Pandas.  All other functions are similar; they check if it's invalid (blank, null of some sort, etc.) and if valid, check if in list of allowable values/transform into a range, and return either the element or a generated result based on the value of the element.

Answer (score 0):

**td;lr: Consider distribution the processing.** An improvement would be reading the data in chunks and using multiple processes. source http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/distributed-processing-pandas.html

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def process_frame(df): len(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    reader = read_csv(csv-file, chunk_size=CHUNKSIZE)
    pool = mp.Pool(4) # use 4 processes

    funclist = []
    for df in reader:
            # process each data frame
            f = pool.apply_async(process_frame,[df])
            funclist.append(f)

    result = 0
    for f in funclist:
            result += f.get(timeout=10) # timeout in 10 seconds

    print "There are %d rows of data"%(result)
```

Another option might be to use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). 
here is another good example of using [GNU parallel](http://randyzwitch.com/gnu-parallel-medium-data/)